# Change message or remove confirmation alert to use facebook login in IOS (I am using IONIC 5)

Tags: ionic-framework

[image]

I am using this plugin

```
cordova-plugin-facebook4
```

When I try to authenticate with Facebook, this alert appears every time I try to log in. I fear that the appstore will reject the application since the alert messages must be modified. I have 2 scenarios:

1- how to eliminate that alert (I have read that by downloading the facebook sdk, I am new to the use of xcode, I do not know how to do this, I am not sure which version I should download it)

2- how to change the alert message?.

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 3):

you can use the property prefersEphemeralWebBrowserSession, setting it to true
here is the documentation
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/authenticationservices/aswebauthenticationsession/3237231-prefersephemeralwebbrowsersessio?language=objc

Comment: This works, the message does not appear when this property is set to true.But as the documentation suggests, this prevents the cookies to be active in the web session, so user will have to type its credentials again even if he already logged in before

Answer (score 0):

Apple Won't Reject it as that message is a standard message used by **SFAuthenticationSession** to ask the user for permissions to access safari (excerpt from docs: If an application uses SFAuthenticationSession, users are prompted by a dialog to give explicit consent, allowing the application to access the website's data in Safari.).
I do not think that there would be way to configure this **very important security consent dialog**.

Also, there is hardly any chance to disable it or Changing the message.

Comment: is it impossible to remove that alert or its message? this alert always appears even though it has been accepted.

Answer (score 0):

From your question and comments I read that you have actually multiple questions, let me address each one separately.

> I fear that the appstore will reject the application since the alert messages must be modified.

The alert text cannot be modified, not because the `cordova-plugin-facebook4` does not allow it, but Apple does not give you a way to modify it. So it can't be a reason for rejection.

> how to eliminate that alert

The dialog is part of SSO via `ASWebAuthenticationSession` and `SFAuthenticationSession` (deprecated). You can downgrade to an old FBSDK version (around `4.2.x`) that does not use SSO, but that is a pretty old SDK and you will not have the newest features and possible bugs that will never get fixed anymore. You can implement your own authentication controller which uses `SFSafariViewController` instead of SSO, but that means developing a replacement of the `cordova-plugin-facebook4` login process.

> this alert appears every time I try to log in

That is how it's supposed to work. It is a system dialog generated by iOS which informs the user about privacy critical decisions, which is an integral part of how iOS manages user privacy. If the dialog pops up every time, check the current login status before unnecessarily logging in. There should be a `getLoginStatus` method or something similar.

A privacy dialog per se is not a reason for App Store rejection, but it can be a reason for rejection if the dialog pops up so often that it becomes difficult to actually use the app. This would point to a broken authentication process, because once signed on, the user would be expected to stay signed on for a certain amount of time or to complete the intended task.

> there is no way to change the text. that's my problem and the reason i
>   ask this question.

Correct, there is no way to change the text. It seems that you look for an answer to implement your solution even though it may not solve your problem - so what is the actual problem? You want to change the text or hide the dialog because you "fear" that the app will be rejected, but you don't know whether it will be rejected. If this is your first App Store submission you should know that an app rejection is not the end of the world. You will be told what specifically to fix and you can resubmit the revised app. My suggestion would be to simply submit the app and wait for approval.

Comment: In the appstore I have had experience on dialogues that ask me to modify, but with this I don't have any option where to do it.

Comment: Modify what? Can you find an example screenshot online?

Comment: the image I shared is an alert with a default text. I have made apps where if I don't change the default text of the dialog the appstore rejects it. that's what I mean. Do you speak spanish Manuel?

Comment: You are correct in that Apple requires you to adapt the description text of the dialog to clearly state why permission is required. This should be fine with the text in your screenshot.

Comment: I have researched and there is no way to change the text. that's my problem and the reason i ask this question.

Comment: @yavg I have added 2 theoretical solutions to my answer. However, you want to change the text because you "fear" that the app will be rejected, but you don't know whether it will be rejected. Everyone here told you that there is no apparent reason why you would have to change the text. Maybe you want to edit and clarify your question.